# Android pinch zoom imageview inside gallery

Tags: android

I'm creating lazy loaded photo gallery (like facebook)

i'm using cusotme gallery overriding Fling to the make single image paging
and using custume image view to make the pinch zoom

the result is that the image is working fine (zoom,move etc..) but i can't switch images

my code
SlowGallery:

public class SlowGallery extends Gallery {

```
public SlowGallery(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public SlowGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public SlowGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}

private boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2){
    return e2.getX() > e1.getX();
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
    Log.d("SlowGallery::onFling","onFinlg");
    int kEvent;
    if(isScrollingLeft(e1, e2)){ //Check if scrolling left
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;
    }
    else{ //Otherwise scrolling right
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
    }
    onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
    return true;  
}
```

}

ScaleImageView

```
public class ScaleImageView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {
    private float MAX_SCALE = 2f;
    private int DOUBLE_TAP_SECOND = 400;

    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private final float[] mMatrixValues = new float[9];

    // display width height.
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;

    private int mIntrinsicWidth;
    private int mIntrinsicHeight;

    private float mScale;
    private float mMinScale;

    // double tap for determining
    private long mLastTime = 0;
    private boolean isDoubleTap;
    private int mDoubleTapX;
    private int mDoubleTapY;

    private float mPrevDistance;
    private boolean isScaling;

    private int mPrevMoveX;
    private int mPrevMoveY;

    String TAG = "ScaleImageView";

    public ScaleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
            super(context, attr);
            initialize();
    }

    public ScaleImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
            super.setImageBitmap(bm);
            this.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
            this.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            this.mMatrix = new Matrix();
            Drawable d = getDrawable();
            if (d != null) {
                    mIntrinsicWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
                    mIntrinsicHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    setOnTouchListener(this);
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            mWidth = r-l;
            mHeight = b-t;

            mMatrix.reset();
            mScale = (float) r / (float) mIntrinsicWidth;
            int paddingHeight = 0;
            int paddingWidth = 0;
            // scaling vertical
            if (mScale * mIntrinsicHeight > mHeight) {
                    mScale = (float) mHeight / (float) mIntrinsicHeight;
                    mMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
                    paddingWidth = (r - mWidth) / 2;
                    paddingHeight = 0;
                    // scaling horizontal
            } else {
                    mMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
                    paddingHeight = (b - mHeight) / 2;
                    paddingWidth = 0;
            }
            mMatrix.postTranslate(paddingWidth, paddingHeight);

            setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
            mMinScale = mScale;
            zoomTo(mScale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
            cutting();
            return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }

    protected float getValue(Matrix matrix, int whichValue) {
            matrix.getValues(mMatrixValues);
            return mMatrixValues[whichValue];
    }

    protected float getScale() {
            return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MSCALE_X);
    }

    protected float getTranslateX() {
            return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_X);
    }

    protected float getTranslateY() {
            return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_Y);
    }

    protected void maxZoomTo(int x, int y) {
            if (mMinScale != getScale() && (getScale() - mMinScale) > 0.1f) {
                    // threshold 0.1f
                    float scale = mMinScale / getScale();
                    zoomTo(scale, x, y);
            } else {
                    float scale = MAX_SCALE / getScale();
                    zoomTo(scale, x, y);
            }
    }

    protected void zoomTo(float scale, int x, int y) {
            if (getScale() * scale < mMinScale) {
                    return;
            }
            if (scale >= 1 && getScale() * scale > MAX_SCALE) {
                    return;
            }
            mMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);
            // move to center
            mMatrix.postTranslate(-(mWidth * scale - mWidth) / 2,
                            -(mHeight * scale - mHeight) / 2);

            // move x and y distance
            mMatrix.postTranslate(-(x - (mWidth / 2)) * scale, 0);
            mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(y - (mHeight / 2)) * scale);
            setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    }

    public void cutting() {
            int width = (int) (mIntrinsicWidth * getScale());
            int height = (int) (mIntrinsicHeight * getScale());
            if (getTranslateX() < -(width - mWidth)) {
                    mMatrix.postTranslate(-(getTranslateX() + width - mWidth), 0);
            }
            if (getTranslateX() > 0) {
                    mMatrix.postTranslate(-getTranslateX(), 0);
            }
            if (getTranslateY() < -(height - mHeight)) {
                    mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(getTranslateY() + height - mHeight));
            }
            if (getTranslateY() > 0) {
                    mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -getTranslateY());
            }
            if (width < mWidth) {
                    mMatrix.postTranslate((mWidth - width) / 2, 0);
            }
            if (height < mHeight) {
                    mMatrix.postTranslate(0, (mHeight - height) / 2);
            }
            setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    }

    private float distance(float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1) {
            float x = x0 - x1;
            float y = y0 - y1;
            return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private float dispDistance() {
            return FloatMath.sqrt(mWidth * mWidth + mHeight
                            * mHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            int touchCount = event.getPointerCount();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:
                    if (touchCount >= 2) {
                            float distance = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                                            event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                            mPrevDistance = distance;
                            isScaling = true;
                    } else {
                            if (System.currentTimeMillis() <= mLastTime + DOUBLE_TAP_SECOND) {
                                    if (30 > Math.abs(mPrevMoveX - event.getX())
                                                    + Math.abs(mPrevMoveY - event.getY())) {
                                            isDoubleTap = true;
                                            mDoubleTapX = (int) event.getX();
                                            mDoubleTapY = (int) event.getY();
                                    }
                            }
                            mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            mPrevMoveX = (int) event.getX();
                            mPrevMoveY = (int) event.getY();
                    }
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (touchCount >= 2 && isScaling) {
                            float dist = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                                            event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                            float scale = (dist - mPrevDistance) / dispDistance();
                            mPrevDistance = dist;
                            scale += 1;
                            scale = scale * scale;
                            zoomTo(scale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
                            cutting();
                    } else if (!isScaling) {
                            int distanceX = mPrevMoveX - (int) event.getX();
                            int distanceY = mPrevMoveY - (int) event.getY();
                            mPrevMoveX = (int) event.getX();
                            mPrevMoveY = (int) event.getY();
                            mMatrix.postTranslate(-distanceX, -distanceY);
                            cutting();
                    }
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP:
                    if (event.getPointerCount() <= 1) {
                            isScaling = false;
                            if (isDoubleTap) {
                                    if (30 > Math.abs(mDoubleTapX - event.getX())
                                                    + Math.abs(mDoubleTapY - event.getY())) {
                                            maxZoomTo(mDoubleTapX, mDoubleTapY);
                                            cutting();
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                    isDoubleTap = false;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

}

what am i missing ? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use ViewPager with you ImageView with Universal Image loader, I've already did and used your code for scaling image ;)